# how to generate custom primary id in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to create custom primary id in database with increment like

- Comp-001
- Comp-002
- Comp-003

and then increment 
Comp-00N

Comment: Create a before insert trigger.

Comment: What you v'e tried so far

Comment: Why bother, surley the `Comp` bit is only relevant to what the user see's, so just add the `Comp-` bit to any user visible info in the presentation layer

Comment: You need to write your custom code to create the increment since that's a string not a number.

Comment: Could it be done to keep the traditional Int ID and just create a model method `getID` where you concat the **Comp-** to your ID?

Comment: @Sanu0786 i didnt get any solution.

Comment: my first question is why you want to do like this , maybe you are falling into some wrong concept?

Comment: @phpdroid i have to show these id's on my blade template.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know but i have to show these id's on view.

Comment: just concatenate it on blade why messing it up with the standard structure.?

Comment: So look at @DiogoSanto answer, its simple and clean and almost fool proof

Answer (score 6):

You need to set public `$incrementing = false;` on your model so that it doesn't try to set the primary key to the next auto-incrementing ID value.

Then you have create custom primary keys .

```
class Company extends Model {

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $incrementing = false;  // You most probably want this too

}
```

then you can generate custom value for `id`

```
$lastCompanyId = Company::select('id')->orderBy('id','desc')->first();
$lastCompanyId=(int)substr($lastCompanyId , -3);
 static::created(function ($obj) {
          $obj->id= Company::'Comp-'.$lastCompanyId+1;
          $obj->save();
      });
```

Comment: You also might want to use [Eloquent Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#events) such as `creating` to delegate to the model the responsibility of incrementing the custom `id` value when a new entry is inserted.

Comment: how and where to create custom primary keys?

Comment: Will please check with updated code. i hope it will help you

Answer (score 5):

Because I believe you can set this simpler and from what you describe you only really need such solution for display, I decided to propose a solution for you:

**Company Model**

```
class Company extends Model
{
    ...

   public function getCompanyID()
   {
       return sprintf('Comp-%03d', $this->id);
   }
}
```

**Your View**

When handling the **Company** object, just call your method when you need to display it:

```
$company->getCompanyID();
```

Below are a few examples on how this will behave:

ID examples and respective outputs:

```
IDs             Outputs
 1              Comp-001 
 45             Comp-045 
 104            Comp-104
 1000           Comp-1000
```

This way you will respect:

-> Laravel natural flow;
-> You keep a true ID reference and a **visual** reference;
-> You do not require extra effort to make sure you find the right product (you kept the ID as integer);

Above is a simple and quick solution to your problem.

Now I am not sure how you are structuring your code, but if it was my project I would even not change the Model and present either a **Hydrator** or a **Marshaller** to grab my object, create a similar representation with only the fields I required on the view and pass that instead.

Why?

-> My Model is a pure as possible with no parsing information (that really shouldn't be the Model responsability for OOP);

-> I get a clear transformation between Back-end and front-end and I can easily change for different views without having to touch previous code (respectful of open and closure laws of OOP);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Laravel ID generator](https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-custom-id-generator).

First Install it: 
`composer require haruncpi/laravel-id-generator`

Import the class in your controller.

```
use Haruncpi\LaravelIdGenerator\IdGenerator;
```

Now simply use it

```
$id = IdGenerator::generate(['table' => 'your_table_name', 'length' => 8, 'prefix' =>'Comp-']);
```

Output

```
Comp-001
Comp-002
Comp-003
...
```

Comment: But where to use ```$id = IdGenerator::generate(['table' => 'your_table_name', 'length' => 8, 'prefix' =>'Comp-']);``` in ```public function store()``` or somewhere else ?

Comment: Yes, in store method or model. Get full doc: https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-custom-id-generator

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code which I am using inside the migrations file. You should be able to generate something and place it where you see the "recruiter_id" below:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('recruiters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // this is in the migration file:
        $table->id('recruiter_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```