# How to make auto generate custom format number in laravel / php?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to auto generate custom format number when creating a new form in Laravel. After save and open new form again the number will increase or change.

Format maybe like this : `001/ACME/01/2020/MJ`. So, `001` will be the number that will increase, `ACME` is static (company name), `01` is the current month, `2020` is the current year, and `MJ` is the initial that user logged in.

So, any help will be appreciate guys. Thank you.

Comment: Where do you get the 001 from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to generate custom primary id in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866420/how-to-generate-custom-primary-id-in-laravel)

Comment: the problem is how do u get the increase number, from db? or from redis?

Comment: @Haris - Its incrementing.

Comment: @TsaiKoga - oh, sorry forgot to mention it. Getting from db.

Comment: Please provide a code or what you have done or tried already?

Answer (score 0):

Note: Hello if the '001' is primary key of table, it will increment when you add new instances however if not a primary key and just a column in table you adding manually you need to get last item of forms.

For get last form number

```
$form_number = App\Form::orderBy('form_number', 'desc')->first()->form_number;
```

And then you can create a form of your text in `FormController@formCode` model.

```
public function formCode($form_number, $company) {
    return $form_number."/{$company}/".now()->month."/".now()->year."/".auth()->user()->shortcode
}
```

Finally you can create a attribute for short code of usernames in `App\User` model

```
public function getShortcodeAttribute() {
    return \Illuminate\Support\Str::substr($this->first_name, '1', '1').\Illuminate\Support\Str::substr($this->last_name, '1', '1');
}
```